# Extrmely high gas consumption in solidity contract even if it is called a real simple method

Tags: solidity

i have deployed that simple contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract testGasLimits{

    uint b;
    constructor(){
        b = 0;
    }

    function testGasA(uint a) public{
        b = a;
    }

    function testGasB() public{

    }

    receive() external payable {}
    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

I expected that txs calling the above methods would use/need (in term of gas)

testGasA : around 21.000 + 20.000 gas (base + store), 41000 gas

testGasB: around 21.000 gas + something maybe tiny? (it doesn't matter)

My main problem is that for the above methods the first tx (testGasA) spent 237956 gas and the latter 230392 gas

Any clue what is happening and my contract calls uses so meny gas for no clear reason?

Chain tested Goerli, Arbitrum, Mainnet, Remix 0.8.17 compiler

Comment: Your expectations are correct. Maybe you could share a link to the e.g. Goerli transactions?

Comment: I checked this on remix. The results are as expected.

Comment: Goerli transaction. Seems good to me
0xbf0ee2035d9be718690f8d8b07653ae31716d46fffcb7951900e9d2506631f44